# New PC with Windows 8 and a lot of BSODs

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, bsod, sony-vaio

I recently purchased a Sony Vaio Pro with i7-4500u, 8 GB memory and a 256 GB SSD. It had Windows 8 Home Premium preinstalled.

I have run it for three weeks now, and a blue screen of death has occurred six times.

It has failed with error code NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM twice and once with MEMORY_MANAGEMENT, PFN_LIST_CORRUPT, DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION and IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. All of these errors seems to be related to different problems according to search results.

I have ran chkdsk and Windows' built in memory test and both completed without errors.

I haven't installed any 3rd party drivers. All the drivers have been there by default or updated via Sony's program called Vaio Update.

I have also run some other hard drive test provided by Sony's Vaio Care and a CPU test by Sony. All of these have passed without errors.

So, any test I have run has completed successfully without errors and my PC is still failing a lot.

Any ideas? Is there something I could try myself before sending it back to Sony and waiting for a replacement for a month?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error codes there are issues with the `SSD` and the `RAM`.

Test the RAM using [Memtest x86](http://www.memtest86.com/). You'll have to burn the ISO onto a disk or create a bootable USB stick. Do at least one pass using `Memtest.` For the SSD you'll need something like [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/) to check for any errors.

If the above programs find any faults, send the laptop back to Sony for repair/replacement.

Comment: Did you set the boot order correctly in the BIOS?

Comment: Hmm, managed to remove my comment... yes. I did change the BIOS options to allow boot from external devices.

Comment: You still have to set the boot order in the BIOS, or else it will continue to boot from the SSD. There should be an option in your BIOS that allows you to set the boot priority of devices.

Comment: I changed the primary boot device to be external. If I boot it then, it will continue to Windows. Sony has it's own stuff there. If I power off the pc and press a button named assist, I get into a mode where I can select to go into BIOS, boot from an external device and such.

Comment: Hmmm. Does the laptop have a CD drive? Maybe something went wrong when you created the bootable USB stick.

Comment: It doesn't have a CD drive and I don't have an external one. I don't think anything went wrong with the usb version, because I tried three different sticks and used the installer from memtest.org and memtest.com

Comment: Hmmm. You'll have to send the laptop back to Sony as the errors you stated in your question point to hardware issues and you don't want to be replacing the costly parts yourself.

Comment: I managed to start Memtest. I had to disable secure boot and change boot mode from UEFI to legacy. It has run for 13 minutes now and has discovered 7 errors. Five of them in the first 20 seconds.

Comment: That is quite bad. You'll definitely need to send the laptop back.

Comment: Will send. Hopefully Sony will send me a new one soon. I wouldn't like to have to wait for it too long, because I need it at school...

Comment: Hopefully, but it's hard to say how long they'll take.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is new and still under warranty, do not go installing any 3rd party software as it may invalidate the warranty and leave you stranded.
Speak to Sony, let them repair/replace it.

As for the OS, Window 8 Home Premium???

Microsoft only did 4 releases of Win 8;
Win 8 RT
Win 8
Win 8 Pro
Win 8 Enterprise

I did notice some Win 8 Home Premium versions on torrent sites pre Win 8 release last year, these were fake, edited Beta releases.

You could try going to the 'Device Manager' (Windows key + X), selecting your device, click refresh, troubleshoot and/or update any device drivers that have any warnings.

Other than that, running Windows Updates (Windows key + R, type 'wuapp') until there are no updates should resolve any issues.

Some 3rd party troubleshooting software is not quite Windows 8 ready and may give you false positives.

Good luck

Comment: Not really sure about Microsoft's naming standards... 7 had Home Premium, and now 8 doesn't. This is the standard Windows 8, not RT or Professional nor Enterprise. And yes, the device is under warranty.

Comment: Memtest won't be installed on the laptop itself. I don't see Sony having a problem with installing software to check for problems. If they did, people wouldn't install anything new on their laptops.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: My comment was aimed at user252143. Memtest has nothing to do with the operating system. It directly checks the RAM for errors and is not dependent on an OS.

Comment: @yassarikhan786 upps, didn't check who sent it, I thought user252143 posted it!